# How can I efficiently pull BPO call audit samples for agents assigned to specific team leaders in Python?

Tags: python, sample

Let consider we have 200 agents working in a call center and handlled by the 10 Team Leaders. Now, i have to given 2 random call for every agent to there respective leam leader. How can i defiend the function in python?

I am using following code for every agent but it's to long.

```
try:
    options=['Mausam Kumari']
    df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari =df_Ajay.loc[df_Ajay['Emp_name'].isin(options)]
    df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari =df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari.sample(n=2)
except:
    pass

try:
    options=['Vivek K']
    df_Ajay_Vivek_K =df_Ajay.loc[df_Ajay['Emp_name'].isin(options)]
    df_Ajay_Vivek_K =df_Ajay_Vivek_K.sample(n=2)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: '''## Roster web url and sheet name 
Link='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V9AhH8h-kHExzTXLn5HW62vrv0LHrcFvjz79fXgcss4/edit#gid=696252374'    
sh = gc.open_by_url(Link).worksheet('IB_Agent_Roster')


pull= pd.DataFrame(sh.get_all_values())
pull.columns =pull.loc[1]
pull= pull[2:]


roster=pull[['Ameyo_id','Emp_name','TL']]

## Join agents details with audit raw dump
dfinal=df.merge(roster[['Ameyo_id','Emp_name','TL']], how='inner', left_on = 'userid', right_on = 'Ameyo_id')
raw=dfinal.drop(['Ameyo_id'], axis=1)

raw=dfinal.drop(['Ameyo_id'], axis=1)'''

Comment: 'options=['Ajay']
df_Ajay =raw.loc[raw['TL'].isin(options)]
try:
    options=['Mausam Kumari']
    df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari =df_Ajay.loc[df_Ajay['Emp_name'].isin(options)]
    df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari =df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari.sample(n=2)
except:
    pass
try:
    options=['Vivek K']
    df_Ajay_Vivek_K =df_Ajay.loc[df_Ajay['Emp_name'].isin(options)]
    df_Ajay_Vivek_K =df_Ajay_Vivek_K.sample(n=2)
except:
    pass
try:
    options=['Naveen']
    df_Ajay_Naveen =df_Ajay.loc[df_Ajay['Emp_name'].isin(options)]
    df_Ajay_Naveen =df_Ajay_Naveen.sample(n=2)
except:
    pass'

Comment: 'frames = [df_Ajay_Mausam_Kumari,df_Ajay_Vivek_K,df_Ajay_Naveen]
res = pd.concat(frames)'